# Nesting in Tailwind Provider and Navigation Container

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tailwind-css

I'm using React Native to develop a mobile app.
I am using Tailwind CSS and React Navigation in it.
Should I wrap my App component like this

```
<TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Welcome />
      </NavigationContainer>
</TailwindProvider>
```

or

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
     <Welcome />
  </TailwindProvider>
</NavigationContainer>
```

In general, how to nest these tags ? For example how to nest if I use Redux and how to bring in store provider ?

Answer (score 0):

Either is fine. Usually, libraries will mention whether the provider order matters. For example, if react-navigation used tailwind, then tailwind needs to wrap react-navigation. But in most cases, it doesn't matter how you nest the providers.

Comment: Thanks. Where is it specified in the library to follow this order of nesting ?

Comment: Nowhere, because the order doesn't matter here. It'll usually be mentioned for libraries where it matters.